# OpenCL doesn't find ATI card

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, ati

I have a notebook with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650, and want to use the card for computing =) After installing AMD APP SDK v.2 (installation was OK) I tried to run code samples, provided with AMD. But there is a problem: when I run a sample, it doesn't find my ATI card - in the list of available OpenCL devices there is only CPU (Intel Core i5), but not GPU.
How to solve this problem and run some code on GPU?

Comment: Any chance this might be a driver issue? Did you update to the latest drivers?

Comment: I updated drivers to the last version (8.752.0.0 from Acer website), but OpenCL doesn't work neither on this version nor on the previously installed one. I don't know how to check if it's a driver issue.

Comment: Is it Linux or Windows?  On Linux some ICD files are pointing to a mis-named AMD DLL (still using "ati" instead of "amd" in the name).  Check the contents of the *.icd files in /etc/OpenCL/vendors.

Comment: You could run GPU Caps Viewer, and see if it reports OpenCL support.

Comment: It shows OpenCL support, but only on CPU, not GPU. But I know for sure, that my card supports OpenCL, it's written in specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem in my Acer 3820TG. However, the OpenCL programming is needed the driver version over 8.753.1. It seems that Acer doesn't support in currently.

One way to overcome this problem is to force install the newer mobility drivers from AMD.

You can follow the the steps from:
http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/177042-force-install-drivers.html

and then try the related-stable driver to install.
(It means it also supports the HD5650-M , but it is different SUBSYS num.)

In my testing, don't install the newest driver(Or you would have the OSDC problem). I install the driver version at about 8.79-8.80(10-11_vista64_win7_64_dd_ccc or 
10-12_vista64_win7_64_dd_ccc) and then it seems that it can work.

Comment: After testing, if you want to use gDebugger, you need to update your driver at the newest version.  ( v8.88 at My testing env.)

Answer (score 1):

Your video card drivers must support OpenCL. I suggest you try downloading the newest drivers from your vendor. Unfortunately most mobile graphic cards are supported by the distributor of the PC and not of the graphics card vendor, so I am not sure if you can find any according drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Not all ATI's GPU support OpenCL, looking into the [list of supported devices](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx) you can see that this card is not there, neither with beta support. So basically you can only buy different card (what can be rather problematic with a laptop).

Comment: Hm... I see my card in the list. It's even not beta.
Supported Devices -> ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD -> 5600 Series (5650).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I have missed that. In the post you are mentioning AMD APP SDK v.2, have you tried to upgrade it as well? (I think there is already stable 2.3)